# AMPscript, rendering literal variable values

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I’m trying to pull in variable values from a SSJS continent block.

I’ve looped over a base name to create incremental variable names.

It is putting out the literal variable names in to the email as opposed to the values (in attached image).  I’m curious if I missed a step or need to wrap it something.

[image: example of rendering]

```
%%=ContentBlockbyKey("ssjs_testing")=%%

%%[

FOR @i = 0 TO 2 DO ]%%

%%[ SET @test_data = Concat('%%=v(@mls_number_0', @i,')=%%')]%%

<p>
  
</p>%%=v(@test_data)=%%</p>

%%[NEXT @i
]%%
```

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing inline AMPscript in your AMPscript block.

This:

```ampscript
%%[ SET @test_data = Concat('%%=v(@mls_number_0', @i,')=%%')]%%
```

Should be:

```ampscript
%%[ SET @test_data = Concat('@mls_number_0', @i) ]%%
```

In context:

```ampscript
%%=ContentBlockbyKey("ssjs_testing")=%%

%%[

FOR @i = 0 TO 2 DO ]%%

%%[ SET @test_data = Concat('@mls_number_0', @i) ]%%

%%=v(@test_data)=%%

%%[ NEXT @i ]%%
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer and that makes sense to remove the inlining, unfortunately I'm still getting the same results with the literal names in the preview